# Ошивка в выполнении крона обновления времени

Tags: cron, debian, linux

При выполнении крона происходит такая ошибка

```
/etc/cron.hourly/timeupdate:run-parts: failed to exec /etc/cron.hourly/timeupdate: Exec format errorrun-parts: /etc/cron.hourly/timeupdate exited with return code 1
```

где /etc/cron.hourly/timeupdate

```
ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com pool.ntp.org
```

крон установлен от рута. Подскажите плиз что не так то, где я накосячил :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле timeupdate нужно сделать так:

```
#!/bin/bashntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com pool.ntp.org
```

Иначе непонятно, что это скрипт шелла. Да, и не забудьте дать этому файлу атрибут +x , чтобы он был исполняемым!

Comment: Добавьте еще полный путь к исполняемому файлу ntpdate, или пропишите переменную PATH. Что б совсем полный ответ получился.

Comment: Спасибо, мужики,  выручили) Про баш я как то не подумал :(